# Touch Controls: Assigning Touches to Movable Objects within Rects

Tags: c#, unity3d

My game has a variable amount of vertically placed sectors (fields), each of which contains a cursor that moves up and down along a bar when the player touches within a given field.

The sectors are defined by `Rect` variables in another part of the code, but I'm just putting what's in `Update()` here.

I had a hard time finding a way to assign the `Touch`es by `fingerId` to a cursor. Before, I tried `GetInput.Touch(touchIds[i])` but there was something like a timing discrepancy between the `TouchPhase.Ended` and the unavailability of the same `Touch` that was causing `NullReference` errors. Using it for everything within `foreach` and checking the `fingerId` with an `if` works, though it all looks a bit monstrous.

```
if (Application.isMobilePlatform)
    {            
        if (Input.touchCount > 0)
        {                
            foreach (Touch t in Input.touches) 
            {                    
                if (t.fingerId < cursorAmount) //limit amount of usable touches to amount of cursors
                {                        
                    if (t.phase == TouchPhase.Began) 
                    {
                        Vector2 touchPos = new Vector3
                        (t.position.x,
                          Screen.height - t.position.y //adjust for Rect-dimensions, where 0 is at top of screen
                        );
                        int i = 0;
                        while (i < sectors.Length)
                        {
                            if (sectors[i].Contains(touchPos) && !cursorIsAssignedTouch[i]) 
                                //check if current touch (i) is in one of the Rect-sectors
                                //check if current touch is already assigned
                            {
                                touchIds[i] = t.fingerId; //assign touch to ID by saving this touch's ID in array whose numbering corresponds to cursors' array
                                cursorIsAssignedTouch[i] = true; //save whether cursor has been assigned or not                                    
                                break; //stop checking                                  
                            }                                
                            i++;
                        }
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i < cursorAmount; i++)
                    {
                        if (t.phase == TouchPhase.Ended || t.phase == TouchPhase.Canceled)
                        {                                
                            if (cursorIsAssignedTouch[i] && t.fingerId == touchIds[i]) 
                                //check whether current t is the assignment of i (and whether i is assigned at all- otherwise, old ID 
                                //of no-longer-active touch could be used
                            {                                   
                                cursorIsAssignedTouch[i] = false; //cursor is no longer assigned after phase ends

                                if (ap[i].paramStat == ParamStat.cursorMain) 
                                    //if value is set to 'cursorMain', reset cursor position @ phaseEnd
                                {
                                    Vector3 pos = new Vector3
                                            (0f,
                                            -orthSize,
                                            0f);
                                    cursors[i].localPosition = pos;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        if (t.fingerId == touchIds[i] && cursorIsAssignedTouch[i] && (t.phase == TouchPhase.Moved || t.phase == TouchPhase.Stationary))
                            //as above for Ended/Canceled
                        {
                            Vector3 p = new Vector3
                                (0f,
                                Mathf.Clamp(t.position.y, clamps[i].y, clamps[i].x), //not literally x and y; clamp values within Rect.
                                0f);
                            Vector3 pos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(p);
                            cursors[i].position = new Vector3
                                (0f,
                                pos.y,
                                0f);
                        }
                    }
                }                    
            }                       
        }
    }
```